# Join two tables based on current id

Tags: mysql, join

```
UPDATED:
Product Table Structure:
productId
pnumber
pdescrip

Companyproducts Table Structure:
companyId
product
serialnumber
said
```

customerproducts saves the productId from products
I need to pull all the cusomterproducts columns
and some how pull the product.pnumber and product.pdescrip from the products table where the customerproducts.product = products.productId

Comment: Most of the code you how is not relevant to the question, you should probably show the definition of both the companyproducts table and the products table. They need to be 'JOIN'ed on a column to get what you want.

Comment: Your table structure is not clear

Comment: I just updated the table structures and what I am trying to accomplish - thanks

Answer (score 1):

You table structure is not clear to me but This is how you can join two table with same id like `product id`according to the scenario you provided

```
SELECT
a.customerid,
a.customername,
a.serialnumber,
a.SAID,
b.productID,
b.productdescription
FROM
customerproducts AS a
INNER JOIN products AS b ON a.productId = b.productID
```

Or if you are not families with the short-names like `tablename As a` and `tablename2 As b` for your table you can directly use the following code with actual table names but this will be little messy for you to understand long queries

```
SELECT
customerproducts.cutomerid,
customerproducts.customername,
customerproducts.serialnumber,
customerproducts.SAID,
products.productID,
products.productdescription
FROM
customerproducts
INNER JOIN products ON customerproducts.productId = products.productID
```

Comment: to give you a better understanding of the structure:  table"products" holds the productID, product, description.   table "customerproducts" stores the productId, serialnumber, SAID. I need to show the product, description from table "products" where the product.productId = customerproduct.productId - hope that helps / makes sense

Comment: I updated the structure and gave a better idea of what I am trying to accomplish - thanks

Comment: @mhollibush I updated the code as you gave me the structure you can check it now  apologize for the delay I was away

Comment: @mhollibush you can remove `a.customerid, a.customername` if you dont need it

Comment: I will try this, I am pretty new to all of this, and I have to understand the "a" and "b" you are showing

Comment: ohh `a` and `b` are the short names for your tables let me place an other thing for you

Comment: @mhollibush you can check the updated code now i made it more clear to you hope you will understand it with ease now

Comment: I got it the query working - Thank You!!!   -  How do I create an alias to show the data?  Product and Description off the product table?

Comment: you just need to use like this `$row['productdescription'];` `$row['SAID'];` you don;t need to put tablename.columnname to show data

Comment: NEVERMIND - I forgot to add the column to the query - THANKS AGAIN!!!!!